UITextField how to trap "Editing Did End" event/action
I have used a storyboard to generate two Textfields, the first to enter a value for Blood Glucose (a floating point number) This is always enabled.
The second textfield is for a Blood Ketone value and is initially disabled for user interaction unless the entered Blood Glucose value is above 13.9.
How do I trap the "Editing Did End" Event/Action?
Here is my latest effort:
    @IBOutlet weak var bloodGlucose: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ketoneValue: UITextField!
    
    @IBAction func endEditing(_ sender: Any) {
        print("End of editing")
    }


Why not make use of UITextFieldDelegate?

Does it really have to be this complicated?

Why do you think it is complicated? Sharing the answer with TextFieldDelegate as HangerRash said, and it is pretty obvious.

Mahi, because it is,

You should use UITextFieldDelegate to capture the textField events such as didEndEditing.
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bloodGlucose: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ketoneValue: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ketoneValue.delegate = self // Set the ViewController as TextFieldDelegate
    }
    
}

extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // Editing ends and resigns textField as first responder
    }
}


Thank you everyone, I have got it working using a delegate, as suggested.

As another option, since you are using storyboards and outlets, instead of setting the delegate in code, connect the delegate in the storyboard.
